# Java TreeMap: Different object after "put"?

Tags: java, equals, comparator, hashcode, treemap

I use a class derived from TreeMap with my own comparator as keys in a LinkedHashMap. Working with this construct I found some weird behaviour I could not explain myself. Maybe one of you can help. I tried to reproduce my issue with primitives. When I create a TreeMap of primitive types, the natural sort ordering should suffice and do not need a comparator in the constructor of the TreeMap, right?!

Here is the MWE:

```
package treemapputtest;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class TreeMapPutTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("simple:");
        simpleTest();

        System.out.println("\n\ncomplex:");
        complexTest();
    }

    private static void simpleTest(){

        TreeMap<Integer,String> map = new TreeMap<>();

        System.out.println("map: " + map.hashCode() + " | " + Integer.toHexString(map.hashCode()));

        map.put(1, "a");

        System.out.println("map: " + map.hashCode() + " | " + Integer.toHexString(map.hashCode()));

        map.put(2, "b");

        System.out.println("map: " + map.hashCode() + " | " + Integer.toHexString(map.hashCode()));

    }

    private static void complexTest(){

        TreeMap<Integer,String> internalMap = new TreeMap<>();
        internalMap.put(1, "a");
        internalMap.put(2, "b");

        System.out.println("prior: " + internalMap.hashCode() + " | " + Integer.toHexString(internalMap.hashCode()));

        LinkedHashMap<TreeMap<Integer,String>,Double> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        myMap.put(internalMap, 1.0);

        doSomethingWithMyInternalMap(myMap.keySet().iterator().next());

        System.out.println("after:");
        for (Map.Entry<TreeMap<Integer,String>,Double> entry : myMap.entrySet()){
            System.out.println("  " + Integer.toHexString(entry.getKey().hashCode()));
        }

    }

    private static void doSomethingWithMyInternalMap(TreeMap<Integer,String> intern){
        intern.put(3, "c");
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
simple:
map: 0 | 0
map: 96 | 60
map: 192 | c0

complex:
prior: 192 | c0
after:
  120
```

So my question is: Why does the result of `hashCode()` change when I add stuff to the TreeMap? For the TreeMap alone this is not a big deal, but as this creates a "new object"/the reference to the old object is changed, I get errors after updating the TreeMap in the LinkedHashMap.

The [Object API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) says for hashCode():

> The general contract of hashCode is: Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified.

Does putting additional stuff in the TreeMap change something in the equals() method of TreeMap? Do I have to somehow override `equals()` and `hashCode()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have misunderstanding about `hashCode` here. Let's emphasize the point in the text you quoted here:

> The general contract of hashCode is: Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, **provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified**.

Whenever you add (or remove) data in a map, you're changing the information used in its `equals` method - an empty map isn't equal to a map with `[1->a]` in it, and a map with `[1->a]` isn't equal to a map with `[1->a; 2->b]`.

This has nothing to do with creating a new object, and the reference to the old map does **not** change. If you call [`System.identityHashCode(map)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode-java.lang.Object-) instead of [`map.hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode-java.lang.Object-) you'll see the object reference does not change no matter how many times you call `put` on it.

Comment: I did indeed think that `hashCode()` remains somewhat constant for an object. Thanks for the heads up. My problem initially was that changes made to the `TreeMap` where not visible when I accessed it in the outer `LinkedHashMap`. But I managed to work around this.

Answer (score 1):

> Does putting additional stuff in the TreeMap change something in the equals() method of TreeMap?

Yes, of course, since the [contract of equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), for a Map, is

> Compares the specified object with this map for equality. Returns true if the given object is also a map and the two maps represent the same mappings. More formally, two maps m1 and m2 represent the same mappings if m1.entrySet().equals(m2.entrySet())

So, every entry of the map is used to check for equality, and is thus also used to compute the hashCode. And adding an entry thus modified the hashCode.

You're expecting hashCode to be some sort of immutable identifier for an object. It's not. Not at all.

Answer (score 1):

> Does putting additional stuff in the TreeMap change something in the equals() method of TreeMap? Do I have to somehow override equals() and hashCode()?

Why wouldn't it? A new `TreeMap` is empty. So with your reasoning, if its `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods didn't adjust according to the contents of the `TreeMap` all instances of `TreeMap` (that start from empty) would have the same hashcode, because it would be the same one computed on creation with no entries inside it, irrespective what is added afterwards.

The `equals()` and `hashCode()` functions for most Collections adjust according to their contents. This way a `Set` or `List` of elements could be compared to another instance of a `Set` or `List` of elements, and `equals()` would return true if they contain the same elements (in the same order in case of `List`). Similarly for `Map` the internal `equals()` implementation is making sure to check whatever is considered equivalent for that `Map` implementation.